# python socket send files

Tags: python, sockets, send, transfer, recv

trying out a new way to send files.  The client will be run every 10 mins to ask server to send what's new in last 10 mins. What I have so far work 40% of the time.  I can't figure out so far why that is the case.

server main loop:

```
while 1:
  conn, addr = s.accept()

  last_ai = get_last_sent_ai()
  new_ai = get_new_ai(last_ai)
  ai_notes = ''

  ''' send # of file '''
  print "sending length ---------"
  conn.sendall('{0}'.format(len(new_ai)))

  for ai_file in new_ai:
    ai_file = ai_file.rstrip()
    if not os.path.isfile(ai_file): continue

    f = open(ai_file, 'rb')
    ai_notes = f.read()
    f.close()

    print "sending file infor " + '{0:<10d}:{1:>40s}'.format(len(ai_notes), ai_file)
    ready_flag = conn.recv(5)
    if ready_flag == "Ready":
      conn.sendall(ai_notes)

  if len(new_ai) > 0:
    update_last_sent(new_ai[-1])
  else:
    print 'nothing to send'
    conn.sendall(' ')
  conn.close()

s.close()
```

Client main loop:

```
if num_f == 0: sys.exit(0)
while num_f > 0:

  f_info = ''
  f_info = s.recv(50)

  f_len,f_name_tmp = f_info.split(':')
  f_len = int(f_len)

  s.sendall("Ready")

  f_name = f_name_tmp
  f = open(f_name, 'wb')
  recvd = 0
  while recvd < f_len:
    chunk = s.recv(min(f_len - recvd, 1024))
    if chunk == '':
      raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
    f.write(chunk)
    recvd = recvd + len(chunk)

  f.close()
  num_f -= 1
s.close()
```

update:
the issue seems to be gone after I went back and changed how the send and receive are done.  There gotta be some kind of blocking going on when it hangs, so I followed the python doc and modified the code and all the tests so far are working.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: What happens when it works? What happens when it doesn't work?

Comment: I highly highly recommend you use a good Asynchronous I/O framework here. e.g: [circuits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/circuits) or [Twisted](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twisted) or [Tornado](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Tornoado).

Comment: there is no error when it is not working, it just hangs after sending the first file. I will looking into Asynchronous IO, but right now I just want to know why this is not working, part of learning thing